# Binary Classification : Prove that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}_n}\left[R_e(h)\right] = R(h)$

Tags: expectation, machine-learning

I originally posted this question on Cross Validated but thought it might be more relevant here since the answer I seek involves more of mathematical manipulation rather than statistical techniques.

### Problem Statement

> Let $h \in \mathcal{H}$ be a hypothesis to some class of binary classifiers $\mathcal{H}$. Show that 
>   $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}_n}\left[R_e(h)\right] = R(h)$$
>   where the expectation on the LHS is over all possible training datasets $\mathcal{D}_n$ of size $n$.
>
> 1. $R_e(h)$ is the empirical risk of the algorithm over a given dataset $\mathcal{D}_n$. It is defined as
>
> $$R_e(h) = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{L}(x_i, h(x_i))$$
>
> 2. Here $\mathcal{L}$ is the loss function for the binary classification 
>      problem defined as 
>      $$\mathcal{L}(x,h) = 
>    \begin{cases} 
>    1, & s(x) \not= h(x) \\
>    0, & \text{otherwise}
>    \end{cases}
>    $$
> 3. $s(x)$ is the system we are trying to model
> 4. $R(h)$ is the true risk of the hypothesis $h$

### My work

$$R_e(h) = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{L}(X_i, h(x_i))$$
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}_n}\left[R_e(h)\right] = \int_{\mathcal{D}_n}{R_e(h)p(\mathcal{D}_n)}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n}\int_{\mathcal{D}_n}{\sum_{x_i \in \mathcal{D}_n}\mathcal{L}(x_i, h)p(\mathcal{D}_n)}$$

Since I want to manipulate this to convert it to $R(h) = \int_{x}{\mathcal{L}(x,h)p(x)dx}$, I though of group all $x_i$ out of the above equation. But then I couldn't find a way to get the term $p(x)$ into the picture and this is where I am stuck.

I am looking for progressive hints that will help me solve this myself. Thanks!